# Dynamically create resource names in AWS SAM using parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I want to dynamically create names for my resources in my Cloud Formation stack when using AWS SAM if this is possible.

E.g. when I package or deploy I want to be able to add soemthing to the command line like this:

`sam package --s3-bucket..... --parameters stage=prod`

When in my `template.yml` file somehow to do something like this:

```
Resources:
  OrdersApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: orders-api-${stage}
      CodeUri: ./src/api/services/orders/
      ...
```

Note for the `OrdersApi` property of `FunctionName` I want to dynamically set it to `orders-api-prod` which is the value I attempted to pass in on the CLI.

I can do this quite easily using the Serverless Framework but I can't quite work out how to do it with SAM.

Answer (score 4):

You can use functions like [`Sub`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) to construct resource names in CloudFormation. Something along the lines:

```
Parameters:
  stage:
    Type: String
    Default: dev
    AllowedValues:
      - dev
      - prod
Resources:
  OrdersApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub 'orders-api-${stage}'
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer posted by lexicore is correct and you can form values in certain parts of the `template.yaml` file using the `!Sub` function e.g.

`FunctionName: !Sub 'orders-api-${stage}'`

The missing part of why this wouldn't work is that you need to pass the parameters through to the `sam deploy` command in a specific format. From reading the AWS docs, `sam deploy`is shorthand for `aws cloudformation deploy...`. That command allows you to pass parameters using the following syntax:

`aws cloudformation deploy .... --parameter-overrides stage=dev`

This syntax can also be used with the `sam deploy` command e.g.

`sam deploy --template-file packaged.yml ..... --parameter-overrides stage=dev`

Note that in this example `stage=dev` applies to the `Parameters` section of the `template.yaml` file e.g.

```
Parameters:
  stage:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - dev
      - stage
      - prod
```

This approach allowed me to pass in parameters and dynamically change values as the cloud formation stack was deployed.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here is a solution using the configuration file samconfig.toml

You can add parameter overrides like this:

```
[prod.deploy.parameters]
parameter_overrides="ParameterKey=Environment,ParameterValue=prod"
```

In the template.yaml (as mentioned in other answers):

```
Parameters:
  Environment:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - staging
      - prod
```

And the deploy cmd is:
`sam deploy --config-env prod`
or
`sam deploy --config-env staging`

substitute prod with staging/dev etc.